# Combining two columns in Views table

Tags: 7, views

I keep on having different requirements and I always get stuck in Views. This time the requirement is to combine the two columns/fields of a views table but display it in different rows.

The eg: fields I currently have: (Below is the added Picture)

[image]

The output of the View in Table (Nickname Multivalue separated by comma)

[image]

While Putting the Multiple value field in different rows

[image]

In the table settings I did combine two fields like

[image]

i.e. **Name** and **Nick Name**  but that only gives result like:

(Here Nick Name is displayed after Name)

[image]

But **the requirements I need to display** is: (Name and Nick Name in Separate Row but at the same column). The Column needs to be sortable like normal Views Table Sort function.

[image]

Is there any settings in Views which lets me perform this? Or How can I accomplish this ?

**Edit:** If this is not possible and anybody could guide me to build custom query for this then I'd be very thankful.

**Edit 2**: SQL Query from Views Log is: (This query outputs the 2nd Image from above)

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, field_data_field_nick_names.delta AS field_data_field_nick_names_delta, field_data_field_nick_names.language AS field_data_field_nick_names_language, field_data_field_nick_names.bundle AS field_data_field_nick_names_bundle, field_data_field_nick_names.field_nick_names_value AS field_data_field_nick_names_field_nick_names_value, field_data_field_nick_names.field_nick_names_format AS field_data_field_nick_names_field_nick_names_format, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_field_nick_names_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_ages_node_entity_type, 'girls:page' AS view_name
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_nick_names} field_data_field_nick_names ON node.nid = field_data_field_nick_names.entity_id AND (field_data_field_nick_names.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_nick_names.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('girlss')) ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. My answer doesn't solve your problem. And I removed it.

Comment: At first try to think what SQL query will give you such result. I tied to think but I didn't create the appropriate query. If you could show me SQL query that you want I can help you to do it with views.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I couldn't write the query here, I will edit the question.

Comment: are you sure that this query does exactly what you want?

Comment: I don't think so, I couldn't understand the query by myself. I also have `Age field` in the table view but the query doesn't show it. I switched the query log as per **@jSinha**'s answer and that query shows in the Views edit page. I will try to clear the cache and check the query once again.

Comment: I can't see `Age` field in your `SELECT` string. Maybe you excluded it from display. As I said first try to write the appropriate SQL query for your purpose. And than use Views module as you have nonstandard case

Comment: It might be cache issue, I have cleared the cache, now I can see the Age. I have updated the query again

Comment: @neok, don't feel shy, who doesn't like girls? sometimes off-topic is what developers need to get the mood going. cheers, its friday :)

Answer (score 4):

You've structured your data in such a way that this can't be done with a single SQL query. You'll always be asking the database for two separate things: (1) a list of people based on their real names, and (2) a list based on their nick names.

But it doesn't have to be this way.

**The easiest way to accomplish Picture 4, by far, is to always represent a person's "Name" as an additional "Nick Name".**

So "Daina" should have 4 Nick Names: "Kristi", "Rita", "Sweetie", and "Daina". Then, all you need to ask the database for is a list of nick names.

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for. But I would argue that it's a more correct way to store your data. Think of the "Nick Name" field not as a list of alternate names, but rather as a list of all names that the person is known as. Based on the requirements of your situation, that's what it sounds like you're really after, anyway. It's a more complete model for your name data.

Comment: I give you the bounty as your opinion is right from the architectural point of view, but still it doesn't satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to achieve this with overriding the views template file: `views-view-table.tpl.php`.

First you need to put multiple values in different rows.

Then in template file you should check for each row if Name is the same with the previous row. If not print the name and the age and add a new row in the code which includes the nickname and the age. If the name is the same with the previous one, then print only the nickname and the age.

I tried to explain it theoretically, but I can help with the implementation if you have difficulties.

**Steps:**

1. Override the views template: You need to copy the `views-view-table.tpl.php` file under your theme folder. This file is located under the Views module `views/theme/views-view-table.tpl.php`.
2. Rename the template file so that it only applies to that specific view: `views-view-table--YOUR-VIEW.tpl.php`. You should place the machine name of your view separated with 2 dashes.
3. You need to modify the following code block in this template file:

Code

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row_count => $row): ?>
  <?php // dpm($row) // You can use dpm() function to print out the contents of $row array. ?>
  <tr <?php if ($row_classes[$row_count]) { print 'class="' . implode(' ', $row_classes[$row_count]) .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
      <td <?php if ($field_classes[$field][$row_count]) { print 'class="'. $field_classes[$field][$row_count] . '" '; } ?><?php print drupal_attributes($field_attributes[$field][$row_count]); ?>>
        <?php print $content; ?>
      </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still newbie in Drupal and Views is my biggest headache till now. 2 days ago I bought the `Views Cookbook` and have been trying to grasp how it works properly but it doesn't explain anything in my case. So, a sample implementation would be very very helpful.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I recommend you to install [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module. And use `dpm()` function to print out the variables/arrays in a user-friendly way.

Comment: Thank you for giving the hint, it was helpful. However the result is not the one that I was looking for, I got some idea how to work with `views` template file. I will look if I can add **Name** and **Nick Name** in same column but different rows with this approach

Comment: The code I posted is not an implementation. You should do some logic, something like I described: `if ($content == $content_previous){}`. This is only a hint.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like you are having the three columns combine into one, and then be split into the two you require, and as such are getting arbitrary data. Try going to "Style Settings" with the options you have now, alter the format to "unformatted", and save. Now go back in and reset it to Table. There should be the option to combine columns, and just choose the two that you wish.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, its just two columns combined into One, I have already done the settings you said. There is an option to combine columns (which I have already tried and explained in the question) and I have also posted the results when those combine happens. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Ah, sorry I wasn't more help. Try hiding the nicknames column and then re-attempting to combine the remaining two?

Comment: I am sorry if you understood the question correctly. I want to display the nickname field in Name's row... I have edited the question too, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In Structure -> Views -> settings -> Check on "Show the SQL query". Go to your view, it displays query.

FORMAT - Show:fields, and then use "Global: PHP" for writing custom query. If you not installed use this link, https://drupal.org/project/views_php .

After selecting Global: PHP - You can use the query already shown and then we can do as we like. All above fields should be checked with "Exclude from display" (i.e., Name, age, etc..).

Comment: I am stuck with this step you provided. I did try to add Global PHP as field but I can only see place to use PHP like `value code`,`output code`, etc. Where exactly do I use these queries? Can you give me hint how to use it?

Comment: You have to write code in Output code <?php ... ?> Click on Available variables
Link.. for example, <?php echo $row->name; ?> check the output of available variables.

Comment: I have edited my question with pictures, if you could provide me sample how could I do that then I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have a Drupal 7 testbed handy, but if you don't mind the age being grouped together, you can do something like this (screenshots here are in Drupal 6) that I assume is pretty much the same in Drupal 7.

First, off, grab the fields you need, in this case I created a content type called `name_nick_age` along with three fields `nna_name`, `nna_nick` and `nna_age` and then created a View:

[image]

And then inside the Style Settings for the Table, you by default have something like this:

[image]

That I changed to this:

[image]

The only change is placing the Name in the Nick column.  This then created this table:

[image]

You gain access to the style settings by clicking on the little gear to the right of Style: Table and while the screen shots for Drupal 7 will be different, I am betting the functionality is in there for this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for visual info. I have already tried those steps as you said, and the result is in the 3rd Picture. I have achieved as you said, but my requirement is exact like picture 4 _(I made that photo with editor)_ because they want the row to be sortable.

Comment: AH! New information! You need to be able to sort on the combination of names and nicknames into one big alphabetical list? (I assume you mean column not row re: sort.  If wrong, let me know what you mean.)

Comment: Yes, I mean column (got mixed up). I mean the column which will contain both Names and Nick names in separate rows should be sortable (like normal column sort in Views).

Comment: Please add this new information to your question as it *seriously* adds to the complexity as it is no longer only a display issue now.

Comment: Yes I felt so, I am stuck in this since last week, really.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php $result = db_query("SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, field_data_field_nick_names.delta AS field_data_field_nick_names_delta, field_data_field_nick_names.language AS field_data_field_nick_names_language, field_data_field_nick_names.bundle AS field_data_field_nick_names_bundle, field_data_field_nick_names.field_nick_names_value AS field_data_field_nick_names_field_nick_names_value, field_data_field_nick_names.field_nick_names_format AS field_data_field_nick_names_field_nick_names_format, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_field_nick_names_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_ages_node_entity_type, 'girls:page' AS view_name
    FROM 
    {node} node
    LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_nick_names} field_data_field_nick_names ON node.nid = field_data_field_nick_names.entity_id AND (field_data_field_nick_names.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_nick_names.deleted = '0')
    WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('girlss')) ))
    ORDER BY node_created DESC");

    $fullname = "";
    $nickname = "";
    foreach($result as $rec)
    {   
        $fullname .= $rec->node_title.",";
        $nickname .= $rec->field_data_field_nick_names_delta.",";
    }
    echo $fullname;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $nickname;
?>
```

Check if results are displaying or not?